# How can I replicate similar behaviour in python 3 as seen in python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have this operation done in `python 2`:

python 2:

```
garbled = "IXXX aXXmX aXXXnXoXXXXXtXhXeXXXXrX sXXXXeXcXXXrXeXt mXXeXsXXXsXaXXXXXXgXeX!XX"

message = filter(lambda x: x != 'X', garbled)

print message
```

result:

```
'I am another secret message!'
```

But in `python 3`:

```
garbled = "IXXX aXXmX aXXXnXoXXXXXtXhXeXXXXrX sXXXXeXcXXXrXeXt mXXeXsXXXsXaXXXXXXgXeX!XX"

message = list(filter(lambda x: x != 'X', garbled))

print(message)
```

Result for `python 3:

```
['I', ' ', 'a', 'm', ' ', 'a', 'n', 'o', 't', 'h', 'e', 'r', ' ', 's', 'e', 'c', 'r', 'e', 't', ' ', 'm', 'e', 's', 's', 'a', 'g', 'e', '!']
```

I want to know if its possible to get the same result in `python 3` as gotten in `python 2` from the `message` variable `without adding` a new line to the code in `python 3`. I already know the `join function`, I would like to make it as straight forward as seen in `the python 2 code`.

Comment: Not possible to do it with without using `str.join`.

Comment: Why don't you do `garbled.replace("X","")`  ?

Comment: message = garbled.replace ('X', '')

Comment: @Jacques de Hooge and @Chris_Rands, the `lambda` is required in my tutorial lesson

Comment: Du you think using `list()` is more straightforward than using `''.join()`?

Comment: @Goyo i am learning python and I was asked to do it that way. I don't think so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python 3.X `filter()` returns an iterator and when you convert it to list you'll get a list of your characters. Thus, instead you can pass the iterator to `str.join()` method in order to join the filtered result together:

```
In [1]: garbled = "IXXX aXXmX aXXXnXoXXXXXtXhXeXXXXrX sXXXXeXcXXXrXeXt mXXeXsXXXsXaXXXXXXgXeX!XX"

In [2]: message = ''.join(filter(lambda x: x != 'X', garbled))

In [3]: message
Out[3]: 'I am another secret message!'
```

But Note that using filter is not a proper way for removing a character, instead you can simply use `str.replace()`:

```
In [4]: garbled.replace('X', '')
Out[4]: 'I am another secret message!'
```

Here is why `str.replace` is more pythonic:

```
In [5]: %timeit''.join(filter(lambda x: x != 'X', garbled))
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.08 µs per loop

In [6]: %timeit garbled.replace('X', '')
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.04 µs per loop
```

Comment: great help. +1 for the `time factor` explanations